# Replace constant value and update other values depending on the new value in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which contains only constants:

```
# constants.py
import os

BASE_PATH = "/base/"
FOLDER_1_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "folder1")
FOLDER_2_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "folder2")
```

and then another script which is importing these contants. I'm writing some tests, and only for tests purpose I want to change the base path. For that I use **@patch**:

```
mock.patch('Package.constants.BASE_PATH ', "A://")
```

The problem is because the constants are also imported in the other script. **FOLDER_1_PATH**  and **FOLDER_2_PATH** still using the *constants.py BASE_PATH*. It is not updated to the patch value. Could someone please help me what would be the best way to achieve this?

Also, I would like to avoid importing constants such as **Const.FOLDER_1_PATH** if I move constants in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to override it via env?

```
BASE_PATH = os.getenv('base_path', "/base/")
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can I set env variable only for test? and before importing other modules?

Comment: you can set it using setup and remove it using teardown. You can use sh script as well.

Comment: I just realized even if I set env in setup, it will not update the folder path values as it will be already loaded when I will import the other script. How I can avoid it?

Comment: Let setup/teardown set the values of the 3 variables. In the global declaration - keep them empty.

Comment: But then in other script I need to define them again?

Comment: no - setup & teardown run before/after each test. Another option is to use setupClass and teardownClass which will run only once per class.

Comment: ah got it thanks. Just one more question, how would I set env variable when I run tests using: python setup.py test?

Comment: I mean only in that context. like python --env BASE_PATH:A:// setup.py test. Something like this.

Comment: wrap it in sh script and do `export` see https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

When testing you could use environment variables to define them differently:

```py
import os

if os.environ.get('TESTING'):
    BASE_PATH = 'A://'
else:
    BASE_PATH = "/base/"

FOLDER_1_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "folder1")
FOLDER_2_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "folder2")
```